# Revit Addins that Run in the Background/Always

Tags: revit-api, revit

Is there a way to create a Revit macro/add-in that will be running constantly. My employer is curious if I can write a program that makes a piece of equipment (for example a lighting fixture) a different color if it is not circuited/not connected to a circuit.

Let me know if there is a way or if there is a completely different method I could use to achieve this task.

Be straight with me, because I am willing to make an add-in that you still have to run every time to check the parts for circuitry. But obviously, the background running add-in would be nicer... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible a couple different ways. 
Best way is probably Updaters.
Fall back would be Idling/External Events.

But generally if you want to update something dynamically based on when things change, Updaters are the way to go. I believe that there are samples in the SDK.

Comment: I will second what matt said. Updaters first, idling events second.

Comment: Ok thank you for your feedback :) I'm new to this so thank you for the awesome input.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to do this.  You can use a filter in your view to change the color, or other properties, if the element isn't circuited.

In Visibility Graphics, Filter Tab, Create a new filter, for category select Light Fixtures, for the filter criteria, select Circuit Number, for the comparison, choose Less Than, use the value .

This will match fixtures that haven't been powered & fixtures that have been powered but not assigned to a panel.